# Run two services in Docker container with two different users

Tags: azure, docker

I'm maintaining an Azure App Service machine. It's running a web application, but colleagues have requested the feature to SSH in to the machine via Azure web interface. Instructions for how to achieve this are here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/configure-custom-container#enable-ssh

I can't figure out how to configure the Dockerfile to both (1) run the web application as a non-root user and (2) run the SSH service as root simultaneously.

One approach would be to install `sudo` and use `sudo` to start the SSH service in the startup script, but I feel password-less sudo would undermine the entire purpose of running the web application as non-root. Another option would be to start OpenSSH server as non-root, but that option is deprecated as of version 7.5. https://www.openssh.com/releasenotes.html

Comment: Ah! That's clever.

Comment: @Henry , I would be happy to mark your suggestion as accepted answer. I'm using it in production now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to do it the other way round, let the initial process run as root and change the user to start the web app. Then, there is no normal way (i.e. without exploiting a vulnerability) for the web app to gain root access again.

Comment: If you say that running the initial process as root has a security score of 1, and running it with unprivileged user has a security score of 10, what score would you give this approach? I.e. running an initial task as root, and then downgrading to non-privileged user on the last command in entry script like "sudo -u nonroot java -jar app.jar". Does this make it any easier for the Java app to gain root?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  "sudo -u nonroot java -jar app.jar" is definitely OK.

Comment: "sudo -u nonroot java -jar app.jar" vs "USER nonroot" in Dockerfile. Security-wise, do you see any difference?

Comment: "USER nonroot" in Dockerfile does not seem possible. The complete container execution would then be with user nonroot. How could you start an sshd as root?

Comment: Yes, it's not possible if I want my sshd problem solved. But in the general case, if I don't need root for anything, are there real, practical difference between "USER nonroot" and running init command with "sudo -u nonroot java -jar app.jar" ? I.e., am I making some sort of tangible security-compromise when I resort to the "sudo -u" method?

Comment: In case you don't need root, it is better not to have it in the first place. So "USER nonroot" is the better approach then.